# Django Model not accepting field

Tags: python, html, django, django-models

I created the following Model:

Everything worked fine, until I decided to add these two fields:

```
Metric_name_dv = models.CharField(_('Metric name dv'), max_length=200)
Defect_Area_Investigator_dv =  models.CharField(_('Defect Area Investigator'), max_length=200)
```

After adding these two fields and running **makemigrations** and **migrate** i kept on getting this error:

When looking at sqlite3, i dont see the fields: Metric_name_dv & Defect_Area_Investigator_dv:

What could I be missing?
I tried to clear all past migrations and that didnt work, so i reset it back to normal.

Here is the views.py:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try delete the file **db.sqlite3** and then run the commands **python manage.py makemigrations**, **python manage.py migrate**

Answer (score 1):

You might need to add a blank=true attribute or default value to the new columns. This could be a source of error.

Comment: Great :) Cheers!